# How to add face to object generated from a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, faces

Good Evening.

I'm trying to create an Aloe Vera stem. I had used a Bezier to create the curve of the stem, and deformed a circle to give the curve a bevel, i.e

- Shift A > Curve > Bezier
- Shift A > Curve > Circle
- Deform circle to create "U" shape
- Add Bevel (object) to Bezier curve.

The bottom part of the Aloe stem is hollow. How can I add a face to it?

If the Aloe stem were from a mesh, I would have the face already, but the steam is created from a curve and I don't know how to go about adding a Face to it. I have tried "F", but it says ***Cannot make segment.***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your object as a curve, in the *Object Data* panel > *Geometry*, there's a *Fill Caps* option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is better.